# Connecting to database when hosting shiny app on shinyapps.io in R

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating a shiny application for my company that I would like to host on shinyapps.io. The application requires data grabbed from my company's database, which I am able to query on my own computer. However, instead of putting the username and password directly into my code, I saved the username and password into a .my.cnf file which is stored in my home directory. In my app, I connect in the following way:

```
rmysql.settingsfile <- "~/.my.cnf"
rmysql.db1 <- "dbname"
drv <- dbDriver("MySQL")

mydb_connected <- dbConnect(drv, default.file = rmysql.settingsfile, group = rmysql.db1, user = NULL, password = NULL)
```

And this connects me to the database.

All of this code is at the top of my app.R shiny app file. Unfortunately, after I deploy the app with rsconnect::deployApp(), although the upload is successful, the app doesn't actually run, and I receive the following error in my shinyapps.io account logs:

```
Warning: Error in .local: mysql default file ~/.my.cnf does not exist
```

I could probably get around this error by bringing the username and password into my script, but my Company does not want me to do this. Is there any other way I can get around this?

Thanks!

EDIT - the way I am supposedly not allowed to connect, even though it works but because the password is in the code, is like this:

```
mydb_connected <- dbConnect(

 MySQL(),
  user="admin-read",
  dbname="dbname",
  host="myhost",
  password="mypass"
)
```

and ofcourse this works for connecting.

Comment: Authentication over ssh is a good option. You should read [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shinyapps-users/J7i_wcU6_uA) thread for some guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except if you use the `RunAs` option on `RSConnect` the user that runs a deployed Application is `rstudio-connect`.

Then it doesn't find the `~/.my.cnf` file.

If you want to keep your code as it is, you should log on the server that host RSConnect and create the file `/home/rstudio-connect/.my.cnf` and make it readable for the user `rstudio-connect`